# Advanced Linear Algebra vs Functional Analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, applications

I have a couple questions regarding [Advanced Linear Algebra](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~lior/teaching/1314/412_W14/412_syllabus.1.1.pdf) vs [Functional Analysis](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~mathav/teaching/421outline.pdf).

1) Do these courses help in understanding or have applications in:

1. Machine Learning
2. Quantitative Finance, eg. Stochastic Calculus
3. Numerical Analysis/Optimization

2) If I could only pick one course, which one would be more useful?

To reiterate my question, I'm asking whether linear algebra at a high level, or functional analysis has more applications to the three aforementioned subjects and what those applications are.

> PS. I'm a first time poster; I read the criteria for asking questions
>   and they say not to ask course selection questions. However, I tried
>   to get around that by asking about the applications of the subjects.
>   If these sorts of questions are not welcome, I will modify the
>   question or take it down. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't do functional analysis without first knowing a fair bit of linear algebra, so if you can only take one course, go for advanced linear algebra.  I don't actually think functional analysis will help with any of those classes, except for stochastic calculus, but there, the bits of functional analysis you would want would be covered in any course on measure theory, which would be a much more important prerequisite (unless they taught the material in the class).  Linear algebra is useful for all 3.

Comment: @Aaron, thanks for the comment. I have completed a course on Linear Algebra already. It covered [this](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~anstee/math223/15223outline.pdf). The functional analysis course doesn't have the advanced linear algebra course as a pre-req. Its only pre-req is measure theory, so I think I should be able to do functional analysis without advanced linear algebra. Taking this into account, do you still think I should do the linear algebra course over functional analysis? Thanks.

Comment: Looking more closely, the linear algebra course is a lot of "you know how to compute this stuff, let's show you how to actually think about it/understand it."  While I like what they cover and think it important, it is probably of limited utility (though not none) for applications.  However, except for Hilbert spaces and $L^2$, I don't expect functional analysis to be that useful for applications either.  Much of the linear algebra course will be covered in an abstract algebra course, is that a possibility?

Comment: I think (advanced) linear algebra should definitely come first. This will open Optimization, which in turn is foundational for parts of machine learning. To make further progress in machine learning and also in stochastic calculus, you need a solid background in probability theory and statistics. **Added after looking at the course descriptions** None of these two courses are especially geared towards preparing you further for the courses that you appear to be interested in.

Comment: @Aaron, yes, I will be taking a course on [Group Theory](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~lior/teaching/1516/322_F15/322_syllabus.1.0.pdf), though nothing on fields and rings. This course is a pre-req to the advanced linear algebra course.

Comment: Hmm.  I suppose that your school breaks things up slightly differently than I'm used to, then.  Looking through the descriptions again, though, I think there are a few topics which will be useful for applications.  Some of the matrix decompositions are useful in machine learning (e.g., SVD/PCA let's you normalize data and perform dimensional reduction), and Jordan normal form is incredibly useful for tons of things.  I expect that the specific classes will find a way to avoid relying on these topics, though.

Comment: @HansEngler thanks for the comment. Yes, I will be taking courses in probability, stochastic processes, statistics and measure theory. I have been repeatedly told how useful linear algebra is, so I was wondering if the upper level linear algebra course also had applications. Do you think my time would be better spent taking relevant computer science courses? The only thing I'm worried about is if the mathematical maturity I gain by only taking real analysis and a single abstract algebra course will be enough to read research papers in the fields I mentioned.

Comment: @Aaron, I see now that the linear algebra course will be more useful to me than the analysis course. Any comment on the answer below which mentions topology to be more important than both of my listed courses?

Comment: Topology is hugely important within mathematics, being used in fundamental ways just to describe the basic building blocks in geometry, and showing up in all sorts of unexpected places. That said, if your goal is applications, then the little bit of topology you see in real analysis is probably enough. It is pervasive in theoretical concerns and almost completely absent in applied ones. Of course, if you get beyond point-set topology and do algebraic topology, that changes a little, but not by enough, given your interests.

Comment: Interesting, where does algebraic topology show its applications?

Comment: @io_cantor - you could try to take a course in numerical linear algebra instead of the rather abstract advanced linear algebra course that you listed. You could then learn about things like matrix factorizations, singular value decomposition, iterative solvers. E.g. how would one solve a system of equations with $10^9$ equations and unknowns? That said, if the curricukum at your institution is not set up to train students in the fields you are interested in, you will have some difficulties putting one together all by yourself.

Comment: Applied algebraic topology is a rather new field, but if you google for things like sensor networks or topological data analysis, you will find some stuff that has come out in the last 10 or 15 years.  Although if I'm mentioning that, I feel that I owe it to you to mention "compressed sensing" which can be viewed as applied functional analysis, so the subject isn't completely devoid of applications either.

Comment: This is great stuff! I didn't know about applied algebraic topology. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @io_cantor Funny, I'm also a UBC student trying to decide which of these courses to take :). Have you decided? Also, I notice you said that you $\textit{will}$ be taking a class in Group theory ... have you not taken 322 yet? 412 doesn't seem to be offered every year, so if this decision isn't about this upcoming year you might be out of luck ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in the fields you list, but I can give you some general information. All of the fields you list require an understanding of both linear algebra and functional analysis. However, in any of the fields you are likely to encounter functions over spaces which are not topologically trivial. For instance, if you are looking for patterns in a machine learning problem or finance problem, you might look for periodic trends in data, and periodic functions are naturally seen as functions on the circle  (in a sense this is *the* special property of functions on a circle). Or you might need to use advanced calculus techniques on non-contractible spaces, where vector fields may not be conservative. The point I'm trying to make: a basic understanding of topology will probably be more useful than, say, knowledge of the tensor product, both to the fields you list and to mathematics in general. Then the functional analysis class seems to be more relevant to the classes you list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will definitely look into taking a topology course. Would an intro course such as [this](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~rolfsen/ma426/ma426outline.html) suffice? Also, I am unclear as to what your last sentence means; what do you mean by, "_Then_ the functional analysis class seems to be more relevant to the classes you list."

Comment: Take it! I based much of my undergraduate thesis on Rolfsen's _Knots and Links_, a legendary text in differential topology. I would jump at the opprotunity to learn basic topology from him. As for the _then_, I only meant "In conclusion, the function analysis class..."

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing up what you meant. Wow! I didn't realize that the professor was well known. Thank you so much for opening me up to learning about a new area of math that I previously wasn't even considering.

Comment: Of course, good luck!